# what is the probability of correctly answering 8 or more questions?

Tags: probability

An exam consists of 10 multiple choice questions, where each has 5 possible answers and only one is correct. If we answer each of the 10 questions by randomly choosing the answer, what is the probability of correctly answering 8 or more questions?

**My work** 
Let $X=$Number of correct answer selected. Then, $X=0,...,10$.

Note $p=\frac{1}{5}$ is the probability of select the correct answer of $1$ question. 
Using binomial distribution we have:

$P(X\geq 8)=\binom {10} {8}(\frac{1}{5})^8(\frac{4}{5})^2+\binom {10} {9}(\frac{1}{5})^9(\frac{4}{5})+\binom {10} {10}(\frac{1}{5})^{10}(\frac{4}{5})^0=7.79\times 10^{-5}$

Is good this? Thanks for take the time of read this!

Comment: Yes this is correct

Comment: The statement `1 - pbinom(7, 10, 1/5)` in R statistical software (where `pbinom` is the CDF of a binomial distribution) returns the answer `7.79264e-05`. So, Yes, you have it right.